# Qt Quick skipping resources from compilation multiple qrc files

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt-creator, qtquick2

As per the details provided in the documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/QtQuickCompiler/index.html

I did create two `.qrc` files under the `Resources` folder under my Qt Quick project.
I have two `.qrc` files `qml.qrc` and `compile_skipped.qrc`.

```
RESOURCES += \
    qml.qrc

QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES += \
    compile_skipped.qrc
```

But the issue is that I don't see `compile_skipped.qrc` under the `Resources` folder in the Qt Create Project explorer, unless and until the file `compile_skipped.qrc` is added under the `RESOURCES` in the `.pro` file.

```
RESOURCES += \
    qml.qrc \
    compile_skipped.qrc

QTQUICK_COMPILER_SKIPPED_RESOURCES += \
    compile_skipped.qrc
```

But that defeats the purpose of having two qrc files and skipping compilations.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting it under the `RESOURCES` variable try to use `OTHER_FILES`